# How to convert this inner AsyncTask in outer one?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, inner-classes, outer-join, android-context

I created this AsyncTask inner class and now I want to make it outer. Here is the code:

```
    private class DownloadDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        boolean connErr = false;
        boolean soErr = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomePage.this); !!!!PROBLEM!!!!
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMax(100);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setTitle("Download");
            dialog.setMessage("Updating...");
            dialog.show();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // do something
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Update the progress
            dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (connErr || soErr) {
                String msg = "Bad connection";
                AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomePage.this); !!!!PROBLEM!!!!
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setTitle("Connection timeout");
                builder.setMessage(msg);

                builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        new DownloadDataFromServer().execute(new String[] { "http://www.example.com" });
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish(); !!!!PROBLEM!!!!
                    }
                });         
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                if (Integer.parseInt(result) <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); !!!!PROBLEM!!!!
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); !!!!PROBLEM!!!!
                }
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Please note "!!!!PROBLEM!!!!" strings in the above code: there are all the errors that I get. I tried to apply some workarounds but finally I could not make it working. In addition I also have to use

```
private Database db = new Database(this);
```

but I do not know what to put in place of "this". Please help me to convert this inner class in the right way.

Comment: Think about what is 'this' in your inner class, then you will know how to change it.

Comment: I also get this error on first line of the code posted above: Illegal modifier for the class DownloadDataFromServer; only public, abstract & final are permitted. What's the matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make one argument `constructor`  to `DownloadDataFromServer` class and pass **Context** as argument like

```
Context mCon;

public DownloadDataFromServer(Context con){
 this.mCon=con;
}
```

and used this `mCon` context to anywhere in your `DownloadDataFromServer` like so

```
     builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCon);
```

and at last called `DownloadDataFromServer` from any `Activity` like

```
new DownloadDataFromServer(your_Activity.this).execute(......);
```

Comment: I did it, but what about getBaseContext() methods used with Toast? And then how to handle new DownloadDataFromServer().execute call under builder.setPositiveButton ?

Answer (score 2):

Make yout `DownloadDataFromServer` have a constructor accepting `HomeScreen`, save the home screen in a field in the constructor and then use that field everywhere instead of `HomeScreen.this`.

You may have to make some of your private fields of `HomeScreen` public (or provide accessors) because of that.

You do not want to do all that though, what's the advantage?

Comment: It is not just a "this" matter, i also have to replace getBaseContext() for example...

Comment: You can use HomeScreen.this.getbaseContext(). Since you have saved HomeScreen to a field, say mHomeScreen, you can issue mHomeScreen.getBaseContext()